# Type conversion adding and subtracting an number index value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can you subtract an Array Object Type with Number value? Furthermore, when you add the two, why is there type conversion?

Examples:

```
[10] - 7 // returns 3

[10] + 7 // returns "107"
```

I understand when the seven is added the array and number 7 are being converted into a string.  I am lost on why the first example in subtraction works. The way I see both of these working is:

Array Object Type (-) or (+) Number Value Type

I would expect both examples to return `NaN`.

Furthermore, the "+" will type convert for concatenation with string values. http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.6.1

If ran:

```
{} + 1 // returns 1
{} -1  // returns -1
```

No type conversion takes place.

It appears the Array Object is being used as a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to to [Type Coercion](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html).

Basically when you use the `+` operator there are a [certain set of rules](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-3/type-conversions) that define how a Type will be converted and what it's resulting value will be in the new Type.